# Максимальное количество меток на карте Google Maps на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

На сайте есть гугл карта. На неё JS-ом выводятся пользовательские метки (google.maps.Marker). Всё отлично работает, но проблема в мобильной версии сайта. Метки выводятся, но не отображаются (если знать заранее где будет метка и нажать на неё - появится Infowindow).

Решил что проблема в количестве выводимых меток (около 3300). Пробовал вывести на карту только одну метку - она выводится. Кто с таким сталкивался? Если ли какой-то лимит на вывод меток на сайте? Как избежать этой проблемы?

P.S. Отдельной мобильной версии на сайте нет. Под мобильной версией имею ввиду  сайт открытый в браузере смартфона.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать кластеры

Comment: Кластеры помогли. Спасибо!